# Auto bookmarking a PDF

Tags: pdf, bookmark

Is there a software to add bookmarks into a PDF document automatically? A PDF that has a normal structure with some headings, etc.

I know that I can add bookmarks manually with softwares such as Adobe Acrobat, but I'm looking for a thing that I tell it which paragraphs are headings (or maybe knows itself) and then automatically add bookmarks into it.

I don't mean how to create a bookmarked PDF from a Word document, for example. I just have a book in PDF format and I would like to add bookmarks to it for ease of my personal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time standard for such tasks is the Aeralist plug-in for Acrobat, marketed by Debenu.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jpdfbookmark](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/) can work for scanned books

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/7DUkvH7_wII?t=30

If you need help to formatting the table of contents from the OCR files, may my question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46984409/3416774